# Object graphs and READ_COMMITTED transaction isolation

Tags: database-design

**CAVEAT**: I ran into this problem a few years ago. I forget the actual problem I was trying to solve so I have substituted it with a theoretical problem involving a linked list.

---

I've been trying to use READ_COMMITTED transaction isolation level for over a year now and I'm getting *very* frustrated with the bugs resulting from my lack of experience. I would appreciate it if you guys could give me a head's up as to what I am missing here.

Pretty much all application logic I implement cannot be expressed in terms of a single SQL query. That is, I almost always end up having to walk the object graph. Inevitably I run into inconsistent state from within the same transaction. For example, imagine you store a singly-linked list in the database and you want to find out whether the list contains a loop (described in greater detail below). I can't think of any way to do this under READ_COMMITTED because the outbound references could be updated from underneath my feet as I walk the graph. I can only see READ_COMMITTED working is for queries which can be represented using a single SQL statement.

- The database schema is `Node[id, name, next_id]`
- Initially the database contains: `A -> B -> C -> A`

  1. Thread 1 reads: `A -> B`, `B -> C`
  2. Thread 2 updates the database to: `D -> B -> C -> D`
  3. Thread 1 reads: `C -> D`
  4. Thread 1 detects no loop although one should have been detected. From Thread 1's point of view it read: `A -> B -> C -> D` but it should have detected one of the following loops:

`A -> B -> C -> A` or
`D -> B -> C -> D`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer courtesy of Michal Bergmann: http://groups.google.com/group/h2-database/browse_frm/thread/8f253177e2b6c543?tvc=1

> READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT isolation level can help you to solve problem
>   with concurrent operations. It allows to performing multiple queries
>   without being affected by other simultaneous transactions.
>
> You could also
>
> - copy data to temporary table first
> - lock the table and prevent updates
> - monitor table for changes (with a trigger) and if it does change
>     during loop detection, your result may not be valid, then you can
>     throw it away and repeat loop detection.
> - use application logic to postpone any changes till loop detection is
>     finished
>
> Using READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT  isolation level is probably the best
>   solution, if database supports it. It has low overhead and doesn't
>   block concurrent transactions.